# Standard Model Extension, Lorentz violation and vacuum energy

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, beyond-the-standard-model

There are a number of theories in the framework of the Standard Model Extension (outlined, e.g., [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9812418)) that break local Lorentz invariance. One question that seems to not have a clear answer is, if Lorentz invariance is violated, whether this leads to a different vacuum energy (vacuum expectation value) in different directions in spacetime.

Would anyone have an idea where to look for more information on this?